# Issues while using PageAdapter from Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, jaxb

I am trying to use `org.springframework.data.domain.jaxb.PageAdapter` on one of my field. That is on `Filter.getFilterEntries()` but I am running into following error.

```
Two classes have the same XML type name "resourceSupport". Use @XmlType.name and @XmlType.namespace to assign different names to them.
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at com.x.y.rest.data.ResourceSupport
        at com.x.y.z.ItemView
    this problem is related to the following location:
        at org.springframework.hateoas.ResourceSupport
        at org.springframework.data.domain.jaxb.SpringDataJaxb$PageDto
        at public org.springframework.data.domain.Page com.x.y.z.e.domain.m.Filter.getFilterEntries()
        at com.x.y.z.e.domain.m.Filter
```

I cannot modify `com.x.y.z.ItemView` class.

Adding `@XmlType(namespace = "someNamespace", name = "filter")` on `com.x.y.z.e.domain.m.Filter` didn't help.

Comment: Shouldn't you add it to `com.x.y.rest.data.ResourceSupport`?

Comment: I cannot edit that class (com.x.y.rest.data.ResourceSupport) either. Anyways, resolved the issue by creating my own XmlAdapter. Thanks